# Bibiliography in ToC doesn't work

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, apa-style, bookdown

I am trying to display the bilbliography in the ToC but it doesn't appear, though I have a bookmark for it.

[image]

Here is the preamble of my .tex:

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  oneside]{report}

% Set line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}


\title{PhD Methodology}
\author{Frs Lry}
\date{2021-04-03}





%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Start of the documents
\begin{document}
\maketitle

% Roman numbering for content before toc and toc itself
\cleardoublepage 
\pagenumbering{roman}

{
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents
}


% Start the arabic numbering at the 1st chapter
\cleardoublepage 
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

And here is the bibliography part at the end

```
\singlespacing % reset the spacing of the bibliography style
\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered, title=References]
```

**EDIT:** moreover, when running in Rstudio the bookdown script, I always end up with this error message:

```
Warning message:
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please rerun LaTeX.
(biblatex)                Page breaks have changed.
```

Comment: Have you typeset twice? My attempts gives the desired result even with the `apa` style you are using.
Please, try to simplify your code, isolating only the issue about the bibliography in ToC. You should also provide a MWEB (minimal working example with Bibliography) with the demands you find here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/231952.

Comment: Did you run LaTeX at least twice after you ran LaTeX and Biber? (I.e. did you run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX, where "LaTeX" can be your favourite flavour of LaTeX, e.g. pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX?) If I try to turn your code into something compilable I get an entry for the references in the ToC. Unfortunately, it is almost impossible to suggest anything more useful as the question stands now. Please try and show us a compilable example document and not just snippets of your document. Please try to remove any unrelated code. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864

Comment: @Ivan, thank you for your answers. I am using the Bookdown package in R and I am not sure that I can specify the number of compilations..

Comment: @moewe, thank you too. As I said, using the bookdown package seems to modify the behavior of LaTeX given that when you compile it, it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found a solution:**

I am using the bookdown package in R and I found a really not elegant solution that I added in my LaTeX template:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Here is the part that I am using for the bibliography to be displayed in the toc

% First step: I define the name and label of the biblio part
\chapter{References}\label{references}
{
% I temporarily redefine the clearpage in order for the bib to not be printed on a new page
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{}
\printbibliography[heading=none] % I print the biblio and delete the default name 
}
```